# Error: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked so many times, but none of the solutions answered there seems to solve my problem.

Most of the solutions suggested attaching an adapter (`setadapter()`) and I have done that. But the problem still seems to persist.

I also checked if my `listitems` are **empty** and it isn't.

I have attached the adapter in a function **`loadUserAccounts()`**.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_accounts);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Swipe to refresh
        swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.userSwipeRefresh);

        //Recycler View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(userAccountsActivity.this));
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewUserAdapter = new RecyclerViewUserAdapter(listItems, userAccountsActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewUserAdapter);


        //Function to load the users to the recycler view
        loadUserAccounts();

        /*
        * Sets up a SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener that is invoked when the user
        * performs a swipe-to-refresh gesture.
        */
        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        Log.i("Swipe_log: ", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

                        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                        loadUserAccounts();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

and this is my **`loadUserAccounts()`** function:

```
   /**
     * Function to load the user account
     * into the recycler view from the log database
     */
   public void loadUserAccounts(){

        String tag_string_req = "req_user_acc";
        clear();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_USER_ACCOUNTS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for(int i = jArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
                        JSONObject log = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = log.getString("name");
                        String cpfNumber = log.getString("cpfNumber");
                        String type = log.getString("type");
                        String created_at = log.getString("created_at");

                        Log.d("Adapter: ", name + cpfNumber + type + created_at);
                        ListItem_RecyclerView_User item = new ListItem_RecyclerView_User (name, cpfNumber, type, created_at);
                        listItems.add(item);
                    }
                    recyclerViewUserAdapter.updateDataList(responseList);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error!=null && error.getMessage() !=null){
                    Log.e(TAG,"User Accounts Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
       if (swipeRefresh == null)
           return;
       else {
           if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
               swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
           }
       }
    }
```

My adapter class `RecyclerViewUserAdapter`

```
public class RecyclerViewUserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewUserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem_RecyclerView_User> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewUserAdapter(List<ListItem_RecyclerView_User> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void updateDataList(List<ListItem_RecyclerView_User> newDatas) {
        listItems.clear();
        listItems.addAll(newDatas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.users_recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewUserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem_RecyclerView_User listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.txtUserName.setText(listItem.getTxtUserName());
        holder.txtUserCpf.setText(listItem.getTxtUserCpf());
        holder.txtAccountType.setText(listItem.getTxtAccountType());


        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            date = df.parse(listItem.getTxtCreatedDate());
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String loginTime = sdf.format(date);

            holder.txtCreatedDate.setText(loginTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView txtUserName;
        private TextView txtUserCpf;
        private TextView txtAccountType;
        private TextView txtCreatedDate;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
            txtUserCpf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserCpf);
            txtAccountType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAccountType);
            txtCreatedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCreatedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when did you get the error ?? when start activity or when swipe to refresh ?

Comment: @TruongGiangDam when start activity

Comment: the error goes is due to you leave the UI thread to fetch data using network, the the recycler view have no the adapter(that time have not created yet).

Comment: your getItemCount method in adapter returns 0 as size but it should return your collection size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

modify that **getItemCount()** to like this.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
```

Comment: Thnx! But, How did returning `listItems.size()` solve the problem?

Comment: getItemCount()  returns the size of the collection that contains the items we want to display and that collections shouldn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Create your adapter with empty list data

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // your normal code

       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(userAccountsActivity.this));
       listItems = new ArrayList<>();

       // create new adapter 
       recyclerViewUserAdapter = new RecyclerViewUserAdapter(new ArrayList<>(), userAccountsActivity.this);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewUserAdapter);

       //your normal code
   }
   ```
2. In your response

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
               List<ListItem_RecyclerView_User> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

               for(int i = jArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
                   JSONObject log = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   String name = log.getString("name");
                   String cpfNumber = log.getString("cpfNumber");
                   String type = log.getString("type");
                   String created_at = log.getString("created_at");

                   Log.d("Adapter: ", name + cpfNumber + type + created_at);
                   ListItem_RecyclerView_User item = new ListItem_RecyclerView_User (name, cpfNumber, type, created_at);
                   responseList.add(item);
               }
               /*recyclerViewUserAdapter = new RecyclerViewUserAdapter(listItems, userAccountsActivity.this);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewUserAdapter);*/

               // write method to update your data
               recyclerViewUserAdapter.updateDataList(responseList);


           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

   }
   ```
3. In your adapter create method

   ```
   public void updateDataList(List<ListItem_RecyclerView_User> newDatas) {
      listItems.clear();
      listItems.addAll(newDatas);
      notifyDataSetChanged():
   }
   ```

Comment: I have added my adapter class now

Comment: It still cannot resolve method `updateDataList()` in `userAccountActivity`

Comment: you need to create updateDataList() by your self. Did you create it ??

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo, the error `cannot resolve method` is gone. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: update your full code after trying my solution. I will check it out

Comment: what do you mean of "still doesn't work"? what happen now ?

Comment: The problem, `No adapter attached, skipping layout` still persists. I have updated my code with your solution

Comment: your code is not the same with my solution. And in your adapter, return listItems.size() instead of 0 in getItemCount()

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works now. How did returning `listItems.size()` solve the problem?

Comment: return listItems.size() is not the solution for "No No adapter attached, skipping layout". But if you return 0, recyclerView show nothing. You have to return the size of data set in order to the adapter can calculate and render item view